# onGpsStatusChanged called only once

Tags: android, gps, location, detect, satellite

Okay I realized my original code was nearly 400 lines, so I formatted it a bit leaving only most vital parts in, so I hope somebody can help.

So basically I am running LocationListener in background service, here is the code:
package als.wakeup;

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class Awake_Alarm extends Service implements GpsStatus.Listener{


public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "als.wakeup.Intro";
private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
public LocationManager locationManager;
public MyLocationListener listener;
public Location previousBestLocation = null;
public ConversePrefs cp;
public ConversePrefs_sets cpss;
int cp_counter = 0;
Intent intent;
int counter = 0;
int batt_level = 0;
private static int alarmID = 2;
private LocationManager mService;
private GpsStatus mStatus;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);      
}

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      //Functions.
    }
  };


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {   

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new MyLocationListener();        
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
    cp = new ConversePrefs(this);
    cpss = new ConversePrefs_sets(this);

    mService = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mService.addGpsStatusListener(this);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    //Functions
}

private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    //Functions
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {       
   // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);     
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
    locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);        
}   

public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
    final Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } finally {

            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return t;
}
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
    {
        //Functions.
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}

}

@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
    mStatus = mService.getGpsStatus(mStatus);
    switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("GPS", "Start");
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("GPS", "Stopped");
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pre-Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("GPS", "Pre Start");
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:

            break;
    }

}

}
```

But my onGpsStatusChange gets called only when service gets launched.
Once app starts it runs and says: Pre-Started, Stopped, Started.
And then even if I turn off GPS, Wifi and Mobile Data + Airplane Mode on it doesn't even work anymore.

Basic layout:

```
public class Awake_Alarm extends Service implements GpsStatus.Listener{


onStart{
//Registers GpsStatusListener
}


public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{


}


@Override
public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
//Functions that get called only once for some reason. 
}



}
```

Comment: Any reason I got downvote and not a single answer?